# figures and \includepdf problems

Tags: floats, pdfpages

I'm having a problem: I have to put a pdf (multi-page) file in a LaTeX document. But, when I do this, all the figures from the chapter appear after the document. I'm using:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]...\end{figure}
```

and after some text and lines

```
\includepdf[pages=1-24, scale=0.95, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{document.pdf}
```

What can I do to force `\includepdf` to appear after the figures? I tried `\pagebreak` and `\newpage` and none of them helped.

Thanks!

Comment: Use \clearpage.

Comment: You might also look at the afterpage package, so as to not waste space.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the figures to appear within a certain section of text with `\floatbarrier` before and after the figures.

You can find this command from the `placeins` [package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/placeins/placeins-doc.pdf)

Good luck!

Edit for worked sample request:

```
\usepackage{placeins}

\floatbarrier
\begin{figure}[!htbp]...\end{figure}
\floatbarrier

\includepdf[pages=1-24, scale=0.95, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{document.pdf}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer: could you either (a) elaborate on your suggestion, in particular including a Minimal Working Example, or (b) suggest an existing answer that already does so?